# parsing at semantic level due to ambiguities

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, ambiguity

I have a VHDL elaboration engine/simulator. As I understand it, the language syntax allows for ambiguities at syntax level. That is, an assignment

```
pin_value <= bus(5)
```

can be interpreted as picking a child of the bus by index. Here the bus is a signal (an object). However, it can also be that paranthis are applied to a type

```
int_signal <= integer(1.1)
```

which should be interpreted as type conversion.

I wonder. The elaborator should take the parse tree, instantiate objects and tie them together resolving the names. However, the parser has no idea if the prefix at the parensis is a type or array. So, it treats all parensis as indexed objects.

```
simple_assignment ::= target <= value_expression { , value_expression } 
value_expression ::= name | literal | function_call | type_conversion 
name ::= simple_name | indexed_name 
indexed_name ::= prefix ( expression { , expression } ) // example: REG_ARRAY(5)    
type_conversion ::= type_mark ( expression )
```

I do not see how can I distinguish between value_expression and type_conversion at syntactic level. My parser parses both as indexed_name and name resolution, when fails to find array object, falls back into type conversion. I am asking if such case analysis it the only way to handle the problem or more strighnforward approach exists that I am missing?

Comment: The ANTLR parser generator was originally designed to deal specifically with such semantic ambiguities. I'm sure that would solve all of your problems.

Comment: Are `prefix` and `type_mark` tokens returned by the lexer?  I think the answer to your question is going to be something to the effect that you have to keep a symbol table around while doing lexing.  When you read in the next token you look it up in the symbol table, which tells you whether it is a `prefix`, a `type_mark` or something else.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to "distinguish between value_expression and
type_conversion" since, according to the grammar a *type_conversion* is
a *value_expression*.

You probably mean to distinguish between *indexed_name* and
*type_conversion* ... and possibly also *function_call*, but you do not
give its syntax, so I am not sure.

I do not know VHDL, but it may be that the syntax you have is the
syntax used to explain the language to users, not the syntax actually
used in the parser. The parser could simply use a grammar that does not distinguish between
*indexed_name* and *type_conversion*, and leave the distinction for a
later processing stage, when the lexical entities have been identified
and their "nature" is known: array, type or function name.

Alternatively, and more likely, it is possible that symbol tables are built as the
program is parsed, and when an identifier is found by the lexer
(lexical analyser), the lexer will look in the table and will tell the
parser whether it is a *type_mark* or a *prefix* (i.e., array identifier) before
the parentheses. Then the parser can proceed with the proper rule for
*type_conversion* or *indexed_name*.

Comment: So, you say that the elaboration can be integrated into the parsing. That is a good argument. I actually see no reason to build the parse tree since it seems to me that VHDL can be elaborated in single pass. If it aids the parser, this is one additional argument to avoid creating extra structures. Thanks.

Comment: @Val There is no absolute rule on how to organize a compiler or
interpreter. Most languages are built in such a way that lexical items
can be associated with a prior definition allowing to know whatever is
needed for parsing. This information is used by the lexer. What kind
of information depends on the language. Building a parse tree is not
usually an issue as grammars (hence parse-trees too) are often
tortured to fit a parsing technique. What may be useful is building an
abstract syntax tree (AST) that is close to the language
semantics. But this may use lexer information (when possible).

Comment: @Val Note that it is possible for a language definition to allow for
ambiguities that cannot be resolved by semantics. But then, the
mabiguity must be detectable by the compiler and produce an error
message, so that the programmer is required to add to the program
appropriate information (such as type information) that will resolve
the ambiguity (search the web with: *ada* *ambiguity*). This is not
necessarily a syntactic ambiguity (what is syntactic?), but syntactic ambiguity could be
treated the same way. Language designers tend to try avoiding it, though.